# How can I configure my Android + Phonegap App to scale images automatically accordingly with the phone's resolution?

Tags: android, cordova, image

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This is not helping at all. I have got 100 px X 100 px.jpg pictures and they are way too small in Nexus 7 but ok in some other device. Is it possible to configure app so that pictures are always sized based on device?

I am using Phonegap/Cordova and my pictures are in assets/www/images-folder. I read from developer.android-page that it should scale pictures if they are jpg, png or bmp-formats.

Thanks for helping!
Sami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android will only scale resources that are stored in the `/res` folder. It will not scale or otherwise choose among alternative resources for anything stored in `/assets`. If you put the images in `/res/drawable`, then they will scale automatically with pixel density. However, it sounds like you want to have larger images for large-screen devices like the Nexus 7. In that case, put the larger version of the image in `/res/drawable-large`.

See [the docs on providing alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for a complete explanation of resource qualifiers you can use.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! So if I have 100x100 images, it is not scaling them bigger but only smaller if I am using app in small screen device? 100x100 images look quite funny in Nexus 7 :)

Comment: @Sami - If you have the images under `/assets`, they will be 100x100 pixels on all screens, regardless of how many pixels per inch or big the screens are. If you put them under `/res/drawable-*`, then you can design which images to use for which device configurations, as described in the docs in the link.

Comment: BTW, if I have div sized 140X140 and I add three different sized images like 100x100, 200x200 and 300x300. What is the wisest way to handle that? I need to resize divs based on the device screen?

Comment: @Sami - Hmm. One way to handle this in Java is to create separate `/res/values-*` folders and store the div size as a dimen paramater that varies with screen size. However, I don't know how (or whether) this technique can be used with PhoneGap.